# Recessed retrofit light unable to fit into can with shallow depth

Tags: electrical, outdoor, recessed-lighting, retrofit

I am trying to replace the bulb in my outdoor recessed light with a Utilitech Retrofit Kit White 5-in or 6-in (Model #LLEDR6/5CCTCA). The diameter of the can is approximately 5.5", with a depth of 4". After adjusting the wing-nut to the 5" inch position I am able to slot the light inside the can and the torsion springs inside the clips. However, as I push the light into the can, the torsion springs hit against the back of the can, and are unable to spread apart far enough given the 4" depth.

I am looking for advice as how to proceed, as I am unsure whether wider clips will work, or if I need to use a retrofit light that does not use torsion springs.

[image: Picture of the can in question]

Answer (score 3):

That product's documentation says 5 inch depth is required.  Buy something else.  Whether it uses the same style spring or some other trick doesn't matter, just read the specs carefully.

Are these things held up just by the friction of the rounded ends of the two springs against the sides of the can? If so, I'd return them anyway. I may be wrong? But they seem bound to wriggle their way down constantly with temperature changes and vibrations.

An LED PAR style bulb would seem easiest, and look good enough until a more thorough renovation is bitten off.